# Adding hash URL and page title after 3 seconds with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Google Instant style search script written in jQuery. When a user searches, a URL is created which is something like #search/**QUERY**/1/ and their query is put in the title of the page. This currently happens as they type however I want it to do this only after they have stayed on the result page for 3 seconds. How can I do this?

My code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search").keyup(function(){
        var search=$(this).val();
        var query=encodeURIComponent(search);
        var yt_url='search.php?q='+query+'&category=web';
        window.location.hash='search/'+query+'/1/';
        document.title=$(this).val()+" - My Search Script";
        if(search==''){
            window.location.hash='';
            document.title='My Search Script';
        }
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:yt_url,
            dataType:"html",
            success:function(response){
                if(response !=""){
                $("#result").html(response);
                } else {
                $("#result").html("Your search did not return any results");
                }
            }
        });
    });
if(window.location.hash.indexOf('#search/')==0){
    query=window.location.hash.replace('#search/', '').replace('/1/', '');
    $('#search').val(decodeURIComponent(query)).keyup();
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to the change the title of the page once the user has been on the results page for 3 seconds. That means once the ajax success function has finished and the results have been rendered, 3 seconds from then, you want to change the title.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search").keyup(function(){
        var search=$(this).val();
        var query=encodeURIComponent(search);
        var yt_url='search.php?q='+query+'&category=web';
        window.location.hash='search/'+query+'/1/';
        //document.title=$(this).val()+" - My Search Script";
        if(search==''){
            window.location.hash='';
            document.title='My Search Script';
        }
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:yt_url,
            dataType:"html",
            success:function(response){
                if(response !=""){
                    $("#result").html(response);

                    // schedule a function to change the page title after 3 seconds
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        document.title = search + " - My Search Script";
                    }, 3000);
                } 
                else {
                    $("#result").html("Your search did not return any results");

                    // reset the title
                    document.title='My Search Script';
                }
            }
        });
    });
if(window.location.hash.indexOf('#search/')==0){
    query=window.location.hash.replace('#search/', '').replace('/1/', '');
    $('#search').val(decodeURIComponent(query)).keyup();
}
});
```

Though if you ask me, no need to wait for 3 seconds. Change it the moment the search results are returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your function inside the setTimeout function like:

setTimeout(function(){
}, 3000);